# Cannot change the background of the container and there is an unexplainable gap between jumbotron and container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot get the following to work

1) to remove the gap between jumbotron and container

2) to change the background color of container-flux (I can change the background color if I change the background-color in .container-flux but I cannot change it by adding another class to it. I don't want all my container-flux to have the same background color so I need this function)

my jumbotron code is below

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Place for a nice quote</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    <hr class="m-y-2">
    <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
    <p class="lead">
    </p>
</div>
```

just below it I have my container-flux code

```
    <div class="container-flux">

    <div class="row first-row">

        <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2 first-card">

            <div class="card">
                1
            <div class="card-block">
                20
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row second-row">
        <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-5 second-card">

            <div class="card">
                1
            <div class="card-block">
                20
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row third-row">
        <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-8 third-card">

            <div class="card">
                1
            <div class="card-block">
                20
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

my relevant css are

```
    html body div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-item{
    font-size: 130%;
    color: white; 
}

.nav-link{
    color: white;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: #9E9E9E;
}

.nav-inline{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.welcome{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 120%
}

.jumbotron{
    background-image: url(../img/top-background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 400px;
}

.first-container{
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.first-card{
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.second-row{
    align-content: center;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}

.container-flux{
    background-color: black;
}
```

screenshot of my image:

[image: screenshot of my image]

The first div is jumbotron and the second div is the blackbackground (container-flux) and in between I have unexplainable white gap
I changed the background by setting background-color:black in .container-flux to show the gap. However if I go background-color:black in another class and add that class to the same div, I cannot change the color.

Comment: guess it is because of the margin from the `p` tag in your jumbotron

Comment: @kukkuz no I 0px the margins and paddings on p tag just now but still no change